# SEQUELIZE: "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Does anyone know how to solve this? There is something I am not seeing. To see if the controller was working, I returned the response receiving the request in json, it worked, there was no error.

The problem seems to be with the controller, but the controller...

**Edit**

**Controller**

```
import Post from '../models/Post';
import *  as Yup from 'yup';

class PostController {
    async store(req, res) {

        try {
            //Checks if the fields have been filled correctly
            const schema = Yup.object().shape({
                title: Yup.string()
                    .required(),
                content: Yup.string()
                    .required()
            });


            if(!(await schema.isValid(req.body))) {
                return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Error 1' });
            }

            //Abstraction of fields
            const { title, content } = req.body;
            const createPost = await Post.create(title, content);

            if(!createPost) {
                return res.json({error: 'Error 2'})
            }

            //If everything is correct, the information will be registered and returned.
            return res.json({
                title,
                content,
            });
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log("Error: " + err);
            return res.status(400).json({error: 'Error 3'});
        }
    }
}

export default new PostController();
```

**Model:**

```
import Sequelize, { Model } from 'sequelize';

class Post extends Model {
    static init(sequelize) {
        //Fields registered by the user
        super.init({
            id: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                primaryKey: true
            },
            title: Sequelize.STRING,
            content: Sequelize.TEXT,
            created_at: {
                type: Sequelize.DATE,
                defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW,
            },
            updated_at: {
                type: Sequelize.DATE,
                defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW,
            },
        },
        {
            sequelize,
            tableName: 'posts'
        });

        return this;
    }
}

export default Post;
```

**Migration:**

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('posts', {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        title: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        content: {
            type: Sequelize.TEXT,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        created_at: {
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        updated_at: {
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
            allowNull: false,
        }
    });
  },

  down: (queryInterface) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('posts');
  }
};
```

**The terminal error:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define all columns that you put on migration inside your model. As you put `allowNull: false`, the database needs the column info.

I believe that you can solve adding the columns that you declared on your `migration` inside your `Model` and, if you don't wanna to declare those columns on your `Controller`, add the `defaultValue` property on those columns.

This will allow to sequelize to insert the appropriate data on those columns. As example: `defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW` on `created_at` column.

Another thing that you need to put is the table name, like this (this is one Model that I use inside one of my projects:

```js
static init(sequelize) {
        super.init(
            {
                categoryId: {
                    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                    primaryKey: true,
                    field: 'id',
                },
                dateUpdated: {
                    type: Sequelize.DATE,
                    field: 'updated_at',
                    defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW,
                },
                // ... other fields here,
            },
            {
                sequelize,
                tableName: 'categories',
            }
        );
    }
    // ... 
}

export default Category;
```

And, therefore, try to import as Instance, not as a class.

***EDIT 1:***
Other thing. The error that are in your answer is on line 140 of file `lib/model.js` ([see here on github on the master repo of sequelize](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/59b8a7bfa018b94ccfa6e30e1040de91d1e3d3dd/lib/model.js#L140)).

Looking at this, try to declare your primary key on model if if you didn't yet.

***EDIT 2:*** 
In your controller, try this ([according to docs](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-instances.html#a-very-useful-shortcut--the--code-create--code--method)):

```
await Post.create({ title, content });
```

Try to pass an json object with info that you want to store and not as parameters.

***EDIT 3:***
You need to import `database.js` before call the controllers, I had problems in this point (follow a `database.js` that is working):

```js
// Imports here
import Category from '../app/models/Category';
//...

const models = [
    // Models that I want to use
    Category,
    //...
];

class Database {
    constructor() {
        this.init();
    }
    // Load on database init
    init() {
        this.connection = new Sequelize(databaseConfig);
        models.forEach(model => model.init(this.connection));
    }
}

export default new Database();
```

Comment: Updated the answer, put an example that works in one of my projects. Hope to help. Check the point that I declare the `tableName`, seems to be this detail, too.

Comment: It gave the same error. In this project I made a user system with validation and authentication. You can create, update and delete users without problems, without errors, but now you started giving this error to categories.

Comment: I put a try catch and I was returned the terminal error: "Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Comment: I looked at the `model.js`. Check the **EDIT** on answer to see if the approach can help you.

Comment: Can you update your model on your answer to see if we can do more approaches?

Comment: Okay, I updated the information in the post. I decided to create a new entity from 0 again, but still with the same error.

Comment: Look at edit2, I believe we have another detail here.

Comment: If your yup is OK, maybe is the Model load inside your `Database` object. Follow a new edit

Comment: It worked! Thank you, I really thank you. I had been programming for a long time, and with a tired mind, I started to do it in automatic and I didn't realize that I needed to instantiate the model in the Database class, just as I had instantiated the User. When you mentioned that, I remembered. Seriously, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem that Naruto Uzumaki. I forgot to put the connection with the model on the file that initialize the models.

Comment: Hi leandro, your answer is much more suitable to be a comment than a real answer to the poster question.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem

The problem with my code was that I was forgetting to add the module name to my **database's index.js** file inside my **models array**

eg: `const **models** = [User,**Task**]`

I found the answer on this post:
https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11111#issuecomment-697078832

Answer (score 0):

In my case i have error in syntax of ENUM in my schema. When i corrected the  syntax, the issue resolved.